# Disabling the previous dates and the current date using MaterialCalendarView in android

Tags: java, android

How to disable the previous and the current date by using MaterialCalendarView library in android, i want those disabled days will not bi clickable. 
and i use this block of code

```
        public boolean shouldDecorate(CalendarDay day) {
            CalendarDay date= CalendarDay.today();
            return date != null && day.equals(date);
        }

        @Override
        public void decorate(DayViewFacade view) {
            view.setSelectionDrawable(getDrawable(R.drawable.drawable_circle));
            view.setDaysDisabled(true);
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

use this

```
Calendar calendar = Calendar.getInstance();
calendarView.state().edit().setMinimumDate(calendar.getTime()).commit();
```